# How To Print to Zebra RW420 from Python

Tags: python, zebra-printers

Ok, so here's the scenario: I have a shopify shop, and I want to be able to use my zebra RW420 mobile label printer as a receipt printer from within the shopify pos app on my iphone. The shopify side of things is a whole can of worms that I'm not ready to tackle yet, but where I do want to start is to print SOMETHING to my RW420 (via usb or lan) from within a Python program on my Windows 10 machine. Unfortunately I'm having trouble finding any tutorials or sample code.

How do I do this? It's been a couple years since I did any programming so I'm pretty rusty, but I do have Anaconda 3 installed.

EDIT: Assume the content to be printed will be in ZPL print language. So basically, how do I use python to send ZPL to a zebra printer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python send label to Zebra IP printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313447/python-send-label-to-zebra-ip-printer)

Comment: There exists Zebra package!